# Attempted import error: 'Outlet' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, outlet

Please help me on how I can fix this error

```
Attempted import error: 'Outlet' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
```

This is how I imported the component

```
import { Outlet  } from "react-router-dom";
```

This is my Package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-icons": "^3.11.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-hash-link": "^2.0.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3",
"serve": "11.3.2"
},
```

This is where I'm trying to use it

```
const User = () => {
  return (
    <div className="User">
      <TopNav />
      <SideNav />
      <div className="Body">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use a feature from the package that is going to be released in V6 of react-router-dom, but the version you are using is v5.2.

If you really want to use the `Outlet` feature, you will have to go with a alpha, beta or experimental version of the package, you can find then all here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom

Those versions arent ready for usage yet and can containg bugs and problems.
To install the V6 version just do a `npm install react-router-dom@version`

Comment: Had to install the beta using
$ npm i react-router@next react-router-dom@next